# Secondary object menu in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I was playing around with xcode objects the other day and I must have done something to the user interface objects and some other objects have appear. As long as i remember there were some drop-down menu objects, some other sliders, etc. how do I get that menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have managed to open the OSX object library instead of the iOS one. Note that those objects will not work with your iOS project. You can start a new OSX project if you want to explore it.

If you just want to open it (using your current project/workspace) do the following:

1. Close all your files (cmd-ctl-w multiple times).
2. Restart Xcode and open the same project.
3. Use cmd-alt-0 to show the utilites pane.
4. Object bar should have the whole object collection (iOS & OSX).

Once you open a storyboard/nib file for iOS, Object Library will reset to iOS mode.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I have said earlier, no.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a more precise look at all the objects in your interface by clicking the triangle in the bottom left corner, this will expand the dock and show you everything in your Xib/Nib file, including all menu items. The only way the recover missing items is manually adding them again, or checking if they're still around in a back up.

**Edit 1**
Do you mean [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBXSw.png)?

Comment: no.. that is not it. it was the area where you add the objects (navigation controller, view controller etc..) but with a different options for objects.. it had like 3-4 different types of sliders, drop-down-menu objects etc...

Comment: Ah, I now see what you mean. If you have Xcode 4, you can make that menu reappear by clicking a button in the top right corner. The left part of the button is a lighter gray and the right part is a more darker gray. When you click it, a side bar will show up, with at the bottom the object library.

Comment: no.. that is not it.. I cant explain it.. i've been working with xcode for a while now and it was the first time i've seen that. It was not something I was familiar with.. The answer was provided by mspasov below